# Как дублировать картинку?

Tags: c#, winforms

есть PictureBox1 который расположен на форме и он производит движение по таймеру

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X - 1, pictureBox1.Location.Y);

        //if (pictureBox1.Location.X == -713)
        //{
        //    pictureBox1.Location = new Point(713, pictureBox1.Location.Y);
        //}
    }
```

я пытался сделать так что бы если PictureBox уходит за пределы формы то ее перемещать в начальные координаты, это не особо правильно и выглядит не очень
Как можно сделать дублирование, что бы после того как PictureBox начинал выходить за границы формы, он тут же появлялся в хвосте картинки.

Comment: Делать две картинки: одну с одной стороны, другую — с другой. И писать логику отображения. Не думаю, что есть что-то встроенное для этой цели.

Comment: Я так уже делал, просто думал вдруг кто занет об каких та функциях и тд; просто подобный эффект видел на css, а там есть подобная штука которая позволяет дублировать.